# How to calculate the result list numbers in column?

Tags: java, freemarker

I'm using SpreadsheetMapper tool, I want to calculate the result listed numbers in a column.

This code is not working when I use the result list.

```
<#function TW nums...>
  <#local sum = 0>
  <#list nums as num>
    <#local sum += num>
  </#list>
  <#if nums?size != 0>
    <#return sum >
  </#if>
</#function>
${TW(result['TotalWeightListResult']!)}
```

https://prnt.sc/r3h137

It works when I use static listed numbers.

```
<#function TW nums...>
  <#local sum = 0>
  <#list nums as num>
    <#local sum += num>
  </#list>
  <#if nums?size != 0>
    <#return sum >
  </#if>
</#function>
${TW(10 20)}
```

reference - https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_function.html

here is the first thing I'm thinking - [How to calculate the listed numbers from the child datastore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60277275/how-to-calculate-the-listed-numbers-from-the-child-datastore)

Answer (score 2):

If you declare `TW` with `nums...` parameter, and you pass a list to `TW`, it will be just the first element *inside* `nums`. That's because parameters have no declared type in FreeMarker, so it's not obvious what you meant.

There's a further confusing coincidence in you example. If you are sending `somethingMissing!` to `TW`, then the first element of `nums` will be an empty string, which is the result of the `expression!` operation. Because `+` is overloaded to work both as addition, and as string concatenation, `sum += num` will no fail, instead, it will do a string concatenation. So first it converts `sum` to the string `"0"`, and then append the empty string to it. So you end up with return value `"0"`, a string, which when it's printed, looks just like the number `0`. But it's not really a `0` number.

So, just use `<#function TW nums>`, then it will work as expected. In case you want to pass a literal list, you can write `TW([10, 20])` then. But I guess typically you don't want to pass a predefined list to `TW`, and so the extra `[]` is not a big deal.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, yes i'm doing it wrong because i only concatenating the 0 and this `${TW(result['TotalWeightListResult']!)}` reads as a string, is there a way that we can make it to split and convert it to a number? like `${TW(result['TotalWeightList']!?split(","))}` but this is not working..

Comment: @AaronMerin Are you saying that `result['TotalWeightListResult']` is a string even when it's not missing? That's a completely separate issue then. Let's say `s` contains the string, then you can do this: `s?split(",")?map(it -> it?trim?number)`. But you also have the problem that an empty string is split to `[""]`, instead of to `[]`. To handle that as well: `(s!?length == 0)?then([], s?split(",")?map(it -> it?trim?number))`. Put this into a properly named `#function` though, to not cause panic... Or, better, that value should come as a `List` or array from the data-model.

Comment: Or, this is cleaner than the `?then` solution: `s?split(",")?filter(it -> it?trim != "")?map(it -> it?trim?number)`. Also note that `?filter` an `?map` needs FreeMarker 2.3.29.